# Can I reliable count on the order of GET variables with the same name?

Tags: php, javascript, html, get

I have a form that is dynamically created on the client side. It resembles a library search form (see image of example). From a Javascript/Client-Side point of view, it would be hard to have each row rename its self with a number attached to its name (so I would now which elements were in the same row, and in what order the rows are). Can I trust that the form will be passed in order? As in, the first item with `name=type` and the first item with `name=value` will have been in the first row...

Image (Note that this is not my actual form, but notice how you can dynamically add rows in this example):

[image]

I'm using GET, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. If you suffix the name with `[]` then it will create an array in `$_GET`/`$_POST` under the name before the brackets in the same order that they appear in the form. You can then use normal array operations to get/zip the values from the arrays.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is "it" in "it will then create an array in $_GET/$_POST". Is it php or the way the browser submits the data? As in, does the browser submit the name with the brackets and then php turns it into an array? That matters because I also program in other languages that might not follow the same rule if it is php that is doing it. 2) Does this not work if I don't put the brackets?

Comment: PHP interprets names followed by a bracket specially; other languages/frameworks that can handle multiply-given names will need to refer to the name with the `[]`, e.g. [`request.GET.getlist('type[]')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist). PHP will have trouble with it (as in, you'll have to parse the query string manually) if there are no brackets.